# Spring Context Hierarchy: How to initialize child contexts concurrently

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext, spring-context

I use the Spring Boot Fluent Builder API to build a Spring context Hierarchy like described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-hierarchy).

Is it possible to initialize the child contexts concurrently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported. I raised a Spring Boot issue which has been declined: [SpringApplicationBuilder: Initialize siblings concurrently](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21608)